# How to fix error 500 from query None?

Tags: python, django

I want to list related categories saved on a db field called "related"

my code

```
def category(request, slug):
    related = Article.objects.filter(slug__icontains=slug).values('related').first()

return render(request,'category.html',{'related':related}
```

y try with:

option 1:
In case of a return, a None on related I assign only the category

```
Article.objects.filter(Q(slug__icontains=slug) | Q(category__icontains=slug))
```

option 2:

```
if related is None:
    related = Article.objects.filter(category__icontains=slug).values('category').first()    
else:
    related = related.get('related').split(',')
```

error:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

In my DB I checked with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `article` WHERE slug like '%internet%'
```

And I get 0 records, so the error is coherent
But I don't see how to assign in that case

```
SELECT * FROM `article` WHERE category like '%internet%'
```

where I have 22 results

model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    related = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    slug= models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'article'
    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s' % (self.categoria,self.related, self.text, self.slug)
```

option 3:

```
Article.objects.filter(Q(slug__icontains=slug) | Q(category__icontains=slug)).values_list("related", flat=True).distinct()
```

> error too many values to unpack (expected 2)

error line 37 with this:

> relateds = related.get('related').split(',')

all the process:

```
def category(request, slug):

    related = Article.objects.filter(Q(slug__icontains=slug) | Q(category__icontains=slug)).values('related').distinct()

temp=[]
    for x in relateds:
        temp.append(x.replace(" ","-").replace("é","e"))
    relateds=temp
```

Comment: You have a list of related fields (which you cannot call .get("related") on it). You can iterate through that list by "for" statement as `relateds = [x for x in related]` and do some operations like split on values.

Comment: and with that i have a blank page with 0 results, and the other categories that worked previously do not work now

Comment: If you write your views.py correctly, it should work. Can you print related and relateds variables? Your return statement in the category method of views.py file should be right after the statement below you get this variables. Can you share whole file contents with us which related with this process?

Answer (score 0):

With option 2 you could try it this way

```
related = Article.objects.filter(slug__icontains=slug).values('category').first()  
if not related:
    related = Article.objects.filter(category__icontains=slug).values('category').first()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you wanted to do, you can use option 1 with values_list method.

```
Article.objects.filter(Q(slug__icontains=slug) | Q(category__icontains=slug)).values_list("related", flat=True).distinct()
```

This query will return all unique related fields for the slug you have searched. You can also check and remove empty values in filter by `related__isnull=False`

The views.py file should look like as below finally. I've corrected the typos and indentations.

```
def category(request, slug):
    if slug is None:
        related = Article.objects.filter().values_list('related', flat=True).distinct()
    else:
        related = Article.objects.filter(Q(slug__icontains=slug) | Q(category__icontains=slug)).values_list('related', flat=True).distinct()
    relateds=[]
    for x in related:
        relateds.append(x.replace(" ","-").replace("é","e"))
    return render(request,'category.html',{'related': relateds})
```

Comment: at lest with this code i have results
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
And the error is on
 relateds = related.get('related').split(',')

Comment: This means that you are trying to unpack a tuple, but the tuple has too many values with respect to the number of target variables. But this error not comes from this query. Can you share the trace or the code block where you got this new error?

Comment: If the slug is None, you cannot use icontains with that. You need to find why it is None in your situation first. I've updated my answer to check slug first and return all articles if it is None.